# Find the multivariable limit with exponential: $f(x,y) = \frac{e^{xy^2}-1}{x^2+y^2}$ at $(0,0)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y): \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x,y) = \frac{e^{xy^2}-1}{x^2+y^2}$.  If it exists, find $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{e^{xy^2}-1}{x^2+y^2} $$I'm not entirely sure how to approach this.  I've tried using squeeze lemma to no avail.  (I could potentially get one of the variables out of the bottom, but that still doesn't help me.)  I also tried considering $(\alpha x,\beta y)$, but again, no success.  As well, i can't find a useful $u$ for a $u$ substitution.

Edit:
I'm trying to use power series expansion for $e^{xy^2}$.  I get: $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{e^{xy^2}-1}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{1+xy^2+o(xy^2)-1}{x^2+y^2}\le \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{xy^2+o(xy^2)}{y^2}=$$$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} x+\frac{o(xy^2)}{y^2}$$  Now, i'm not sure how to deal with the $\frac{o(xy^2)}{y^2}$.  I'm not sure if i'm just digging myself a deeper hole, or if i'm getting somewhere with this technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that
your start is reasonable.

To get a bound on
the error in the
power series for $e^x$
after $n$ terms,

$\begin{array}\\
e^x
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{x^k}{k!}+\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}\\
\end{array}
$

so,
if $|x| < 1$,

$\begin{array}\\
|e^x-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{x^k}{k!}|
&=|\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}|\\
&\le|\frac1{n!}\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} x^k|\\
&\le|\frac{x^n}{(1-x)n!}|\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if $|xy^2| < \frac12$,
$|e^{xy^2}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(xy^2)^k}{k!}|
\le|\frac{(xy^2)^n}{(1-xy^2)n!}|
\le|\frac{2(xy^2)^n}{n!}|
$.

Setting $n=1$,
$|e^{xy^2}-1|
\le|2xy^2|
$
or
$\frac{|e^{xy^2}-1|}{x^2+y^2}
\le\frac{|2xy^2|}{x^2+y^2}
\le\frac{|2x|}{(x/y)^2+1}
\le|2x|
$
so the limit is zero.

Comment: This is good and makes sense to me.  However, it occurs to me to try something based off of what you showed.  looking back on my attempt:  Is it necessary to include $o(xy^2)$ in my estimation?  If I leave it out, I get the same bound that you get.  Is this acceptable?  I'm guess i'm not completely comfortable with little o notation.

Comment: Nevermind, this works for small $x,y$.  Hence the step in your solution "if $|xy^2|<1/2$".  Coolio.

Answer (score 0):

Found an "easier" way to go about finding the limit of this function.  $$0 \le \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{|e^{xy^2}-1|}{x^2+y^2} = \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{|e^{xy^2}-1|}{|xy^2|}*\frac{|xy^2|}{x^2+y^2}$$
$$ =\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{|e^{xy^2}-1|}{|xy^2|}*\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{|xy^2|}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{u \to 0}\frac{|e^u-1|}{u}*\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{|xy^2|}{x^2+y^2}$$
$$=1*\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{|xy^2|}{x^2+y^2}\le \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{|x|y^2}{y^2}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} |x| = 0$$
So, by the squeeze theorem, $f(x,y)$ $\to$ 0 as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$.